# Why is my MRTK 3 Android AR App background black?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I have set up a test with MRTK 3. I have tried to run this on my Android Phone. Touch inputs are detected. Even the movements of the smartphone are detected. The camera is displayed in Android as used.
However, there is no camera input in the application.

[This is how the app looks on the Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxl9I.jpg)

[Android Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHi08.png)
[`XR` Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94WGa.png)
[Main Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C872l.png)

[After building, these two points must be fixed again and again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Csfg.png)

I tried to find a settings error but could not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your package name it seems you're using URP. Have you added the *AR Background Renderer Feature* to the render feature stack of the render pipeline?

- Select your pipeline asset
- Click 'Add render feature'
- Click 'Add AR renderer feature'